# track software DOWNLOAD

Tags: google-analytics, download, software-distribution, usage-statistics

I have a simple question here. Let say you have a website on which you have a software with links to download and install it on your computer. Is it possible to find out who or how many people have DOWNLOAD the software on their computer with something like Google Analytics for example? If we cannot get that information with Google Analytics, please provide me the tools that I can use to get that information.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to include code in your installation program to "phone home" and let you know that the user not just downloaded, but actually installed your software.

Of course, this kind of action, if anyone should implement it, should always ask for explicit consent from the user, because, if done silently, could rightfully be qualified as malware/spyware, in my opinion.

Comment: Google Analytics, as far as I know, can't track what happens after your user has downloaded a file from your web site.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in whether the user has DOWNLOADED the software than in whether he/she has INSTALLED it